# Python 2.7 Script in Virtual Environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, command-prompt

I am running a Python 2.7 script that has specific dependencies/libraries (contained in a virtual environment) using anaconda prompt. Is there a way to run the script using code in a python 3 .py file in a different environment? Something like a library that allows me to open anaconda prompt in a specific environment (to then run the python 2.7 script). I couldn't seem to find it online. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to run a Python 3 script (in a Python 3 virtual env) that imports a python 2.7 module that has specific dependencies captured in a Python 2 virtual env. The reason is because I am selectively downloading large amounts of data depending on what is needed in the Python 3 script. It is unrealistic to download all the data and process through it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can select the environment from the drop-down box in the Anaconda Navigator home page if you have your virtual environment in Anaconda itself. 
Or you can use

`conda activate env-name`

If you have your base conda in your terminal as default or else activate using

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

then run

```
conda activate env-name
```

Hope this helps.